# Unable to save category image on Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

Im using Magento 2.3.1 and im unable to save the category image, the strange thing is i can save the title, the content and everything else.

I have tested on a fresh install and it works, so it looks like its my db broken.

I need to know witch tables are involved on this?, maybe something related to attributes?

I have also changed the template and same error, so this is a db issue. Something related to the ids.

Please note also when i access to Catalog->Product on dashboard im getting this:

```
Can't check requested quantity for products without Source Items support.
```